# Sorting a multidimensional array in awk

Tags: awk

I am trying to sort a multidimensional array in ascending order. What am i doing wrong?

```
  for (i=0; i in avg; i++)
        for (j=0; j<=i; j++)
           if (avg[j]>avg[j+1])
           {
                temp=a[j];
                avg[j]=a[j+1];
                avg[j+1]=temp;         
           }
```

Sample input 1.43  2.14 1.57

Exped output 1.43 1.57 2.14

Comment: it didn't work i have the feeling that i am not referencing elements the propper way

Comment: is bubble sort ? are `a` and `avg` arrays differents?

Comment: please give sample input and expected o/p

Comment: yep my bad but it still does not work

Comment: where are the multiple dimensions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using bubble sorting, you have several errors .... I show an example working

```
awk '
    BEGIN{
    n = split("1.43 2.14 1.57", avg, " ")
    for (i=1; i<=n-1; ++i)
        for (j=i+1; j<=n; ++j)
            if (avg[i]>avg[j]){
                temp=avg[j]
                avg[j]=avg[i]
                avg[i]=temp        
            }
    for (i=1; i<=n; ++i) printf "%s%s",avg[i],(i==n?ORS:OFS)
}'
```

you get,

```
1.43 1.57 2.14
```

Answer (score 3):

Your array is not multidimensional. In any case, to sort an array using GNU awk for "sorted_in":

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{
    split("1.43 2.14 1.57",a)

    print "ascending:"
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@val_num_asc"
    for (i in a) print a[i]

    print "\ndescending:"
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@val_num_desc"
    for (i in a) print a[i]
}'
ascending:
1.43
1.57
2.14

descending:
2.14
1.57
1.43
```

Comment: `^1` nice presentation of sorted_in.

Answer (score 1):

Also, if you have access to gawk extensions you can use [`asort()`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Array-Sorting-Functions.html) :

```
awk 'BEGIN{
        a[1]=1.43;
        a[2]=2.14;
        a[3]=1.57; 

        n = asort(a); 

        for(j = 1; j <= n; j++) { 
            print a[j] 
        }
     }'
```